# Updating a node module doesn't affect the program

Tags: node.js

I'm experiencing something weird.

I have a node project that uses an external module imported with `npm` into the `node_modules` directory.

Now I am making a change in the node module code and when I run my app the change doesn't kick in (I know because i've put `console.log()` there).

Am I missing something here ? Does node caches it's modules somehow ? Or does it sound like something local ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should definitely work.

However, if the same module is also included as a dependency of an other module, it would be inside the node_modules of that module.  And if that's the one being used, this is the one you would need to change.

Comment: It turns out I had two different `node_modules` directories in the same project and I was changing the wrong one. You assured me that I had to look for my problem somewhere else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your node_modules folder. If you find the .cache folder, this may be the reason.

You can delete this folder and restart you project for verification.